# unit testing a controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller

I'm fairly new to angular unit testing and I know this kind of question has been asked before...the answers given do not resolve my problem (or lack of insight)

I have a simple controller called testController that has one scope property..

```
'use strict';
angular.module('eventsApp').controller('testController',
function testController($scope) {

    $scope.claimId = 123456;

});
```

and I have a test for the controller...

```
describe('testController', function () {

var scope;
var controller;

beforeEach(module('eventsApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function () {
        return $controller('testController', {
            $scope: scope
        });

    };

}));


it('expects claim id scope to be 123456', function () {
        controller = createController();
        expect(scope.claimId).toBe(123456);
    });
});
```

However the error message I keep getting is ...Argument 'testController' is not a function, got undefined ....

I'm slowly losing the will to live..please can somebody help?

Incidently my module is defined as :

```
'use strict';
 var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.grid',                'ui.grid.selection', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize']);

eventsApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
}
// disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997            05:00:00 GMT';

}]);
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add the controller JS file in the list of karma files. The exact and complete error message would help. Also, don't define global functions such as createController. Assign it to a local variable of the describe callback function, just as you do with scope.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and yes I will define future functions to local variables. Well the test passed this morning and so I thing it must have been something to do with karma ....thanks for answering anyway